# can HttpSession object configured in xml bean java spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, javabeans, httpsession

can i configure HttpSession in spring bean xml configuration file ?
i have to create HttpSession fectory so i can use this all session objects to every where.

is there any way to put object under HttpSession with xml configuration file ??

Comment: The container manages http sessions, so spring shouldn't have any hand in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `DelegatingHttpSessionListenerProxy` in similary way that the framework `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

For example (very simple and not tested)

```
public class DelegatingHttpSessionListenerProxy implements HttpSessionListener {
    private HttpSessionListener delegate;
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        if (wac == null) {
            wac = findWebApplicationContext(event);
        }

        if (wac != null) {
            delegate = wac.getBean(HttpSessionListener.class);
            delegate.sessionCreated(event);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        if (wac == null) {
            wac = findWebApplicationContext(event);
        }

        if (wac != null) {
            delegate = wac.getBean(HttpSessionListener.class);
            delegate.sessionDestroyed(event);
        }
    }

    protected WebApplicationContext findWebApplicationContext(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        return WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getSession().getServletContext());
    }
```

Then, register the proxy in web.xml and manage your real implementation in the application context.